# Add multiple values to map using same key?

Tags: java

This is what I have so far

```
Map<String, String> courses = new HashMap();
courses.put("Teachers","adam");
```

so how do I add more teachers using the same key

Comment: Then it should be `Map<String, List<String>> courses`

Comment: And `new HashMap<>()`. (Don't use raw types)

Comment: I am getting error if i use "List"

Comment: You will have to first make sure the "Teachers" key exists in courses map, then you have to do courses.get("Teachers").add("adam"). The only downside to using Map<String, List<String>> is that all keys have to be lists now, so you'll have to update all references to courses variable.

Comment: Post the error @salmaan

Comment: use `Map<String ,List<String>> `instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Map<String, ArrayList<String>>`. Then add additional information by doing `map.get("Teachers").add("Bob")`

Comment: how do you add new key

Comment: map.put("Teachers", new ArrayList ());

Comment: map.get("Teachers") gives you an ArrayList, so you can access it's values using an index or .contains("Bob") or .indexOf("Bob")

Answer (score 0):

You can benefit from [computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-):

```
Map<String, List<String>> courses = new HashMap<>();
courses.computeIfAbsent("Teachers", k -> new ArrayList<>()).add("adam");
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can use google guava,`Interface Multimap<K,V>` is a good way to do this,and all opereation is simple。

To add a dependency on Guava using Maven, use the following:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
  <version>27.0.1-jre</version>
  <!-- or, for Android: -->
  <version>27.0.1-android</version>
</dependency>
```